# Can I share the resolution of a CSS issue that I was having?

Tags: discussion

I recently ran into a problem with my CSS linking code and was unable to find the answer to my question with multiple searches. Specifically, I was trying to understand why my CSS stylesheet was working with Safari but failed to even load with Chrome or Firefox.

My original code:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='css/text' href='./main.css'>
```

Once I corrected the **type entry** as follows it worked correctly:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='./main.css'>
```

Thinking others might find this useful when searching for something like:

> Why is CSS loading with Safari but not with Chrome?

Since I am still pretty new to this site and want to be helpful, how should I best proceed with sharing this kind of potentially helpful info?

Comment: it's seems a typo issue for me ... following any good tutorial will give you a correct syntax, you have a low chance to find this wrong within good ressources.

Answer (score 8):

If you had a more complex question, you could [post a question and self-answer it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

But your issue was based on a typo, as [@TemaniAfif pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377899/posting-helpful-finding#comment656649_377899). As such, the question would be off-topic. It would be like asking why your code didn't work if it began with `<lnik` instead of `<link`. That's not actually likely to help other users.

P.S. The Safari/Chrome issue *as you phrased it* is a bit of a red herring. It only works in Safari because, apparently, Safari ignores the `type` attribute here. That's arguably a bug in Safari, but it's not really the heart of the problem you were having.

But, as discussed in the comments below, you could pose the question in a way that puts the typo front and center and focuses on why the browsers handle it differently. I didn’t make this clear in the first version of this answer, but I actually think that would be a good question. (If that’s what you were originally proposing, then I apologize for any confusion.)

Comment: Counterargument: Safari's unexpected behavior being the single most immediately apparent symptom of an otherwise trivial issue might actually be why the question may help other users. Alternatively, the question could be framed as "Why does Safari treat this typo differently/ignore this typo?" and the answer would be "it's Safari."

Comment: I actually think that could be a very good question. It just would be structured differently. What I mean is that OP’s question (“Why does this work in Safari but not Chrome?”) and answer (“It’s a typo.”) as originally proposed would be off-topic. The question you posed would be much better and could lead to deeper, non-typo-based answers about Safari internals and CSS standards.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think the question should be required to acknowledge the typo or state that it was intentional in order to be on-topic. After all, it still boils down to an incorrect MIME type, and while certainly I can't say I've ever seen anyone else misspell a MIME type this way, the question is already asking why different browsers are behaving differently. But yeah, I do believe my suggestion is an improvement over the original phrasing.

Comment: Fair enough. I do actually think it’s very interesting that Safari is willing to run with this CSS and ignore an incorrect MIME type. I don’t mean to imply that OP has to say, “I made a typo.” More that the question would need to state that an incorrect MIME type does work in Safari (and would preferably give an example).

Comment: Good discussion. My question was intended to draw attention to how different browsers handle this MIME type syntax error and hopefully save someone time in the future as it would be an easy mistake to make. Not sure it matters but I personally don't see this as a typo per se. One might also argue that Safari more appropriately interprets user intent especially given filename reference ends in .css and that Chrome is more strict but that would be yet another topic. In any case, I was hoping to get a flavor for how this site interprets value so thank you!